# JavaScript RegExp : Why causes a double backslash ( \\ ) an error?

Tags: javascript, regex

Have found this out by accident and have no idea what's the reason.

```
// Results in "Syntax error in regular Expression".
var re = RegExp('\\');
```

I know that the constructor-function expects a string as parameter. And that the backslash is used within strings to escape characters with special meaning. I know that I have to escape characters like \d to \\d .

So therefore: The right backslash should the interpreted as some normal character.

Instead it throws an error. Why?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Because `/\/` is an invalid regular expression. If you want a regex to match a single backslash, you'll need either `/\\/` or `new RegExp('\\\\')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is that the *effective* regex which you are feeding into the JavaScript engine is a single backslash `\`.

The reason for this is that the first backslash *escapes* the second one.  So you are putting in a literal backslash, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're right. " var test1 = '\'; " The backslash escapes the second apostrophe. So the string has no ending sign and is invalid. Something like that can't exist. Shortest possible string consisting of nothing but a backslash would be " var test2 = '\\' " . Therefore a RegExp searching for test1 would make no sense. Thanks for the help. You gave the correct input.

Answer (score 5):

`\` is used to escape `\` in strings, so to get `\d` as you wrote you need to do `\\d`.

Also in regexp you need to escape `\` with `\\`.

So you have two escape syntaxes that need to take place in regexps, using a single `\\` will mean `\` in regexp which is not correct, because it needs to be escaped.

So to workaround this you need double escape: `\\\\` - this will be a regex looking for `\`.

Answer (score 4):

The string literal `'\\'` creates a string containing nothing but a single backslash character, because within string literals the backslash is an escape character.

A single backslash character is not a valid regular expression.

If you want a regex that *matches* a single backslash then that needs to be escaped within the regex, so you need to do either:

```
re = /\\/;
// or
re = new RegExp('\\\\');
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash \ is the escape character for regular expressions. Therefore a double backslash would indeed mean a single, literal backslash. \ (backslash) followed by any of [\^$. ?*+(){} escapes the special character to suppress its special meaning.